# What is the work-around to fix issue related to ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I am getting the below errors
**1.SCRIPT5022: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. 
2.SCRIPT5009: 'Sys' is undefined**.

I have tried all the ways provided in googling the Error Text.Application(.NET 4.0) is working on IIS6.0

Can any once help me regrding this ?

Comment: Do you have any type of routing enabled?

Comment: No I dont have any routing mechanism. Its not MVC Project.

Comment: OK. You can use routing in webforms, and it can cause this error. Another cause could be invalid HTML. Have you validated your output?

Answer (score 0):

Set EnableCdn property of script manager to true
Like this:

i have the same problem and solving them with this property!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by correcting the rewrite rule...

I changed match url="^(.*)$" to match url="^(.aspx)$"